# Publicly Available PCAP dumps that associate IP addresses with Operating System?

Tags: operating-systems, machine-learning

I am currently working on a machine learning module to detect Operating Systems based on existing packet traffic in pcap file format. So far, I have generated some traffic of popular Operating Systems available. However, this process is very tedious.

I would like to know if there is any publicly available pcap files that associates data generated from a particular Operating System (e.g. pcap file that have a lot of traffic from Windows XP). I am aware that there are other similar questions asked regarding publicly available pcap files, however none of them seem to be focused on Operating Systems.

Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions of the type "where can I find X?" are off-topic as the answer can change from day to day. We get a lot of people asking for repos for ML research. It doesn't matter what the traffic type is.

Comment: There is already a tool that does this. **P0f** , https://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/p0f3/